# Single page feedback page to store data

Tags: java, javascript, html

I have a single page for getting feedback for a set of questions and answers to choose from. 50 users are going to provide feedback for the questions. After the users have given the rating for the feedback questions, I need to do some calculation and need to generate a report in excel format.

Is it possible to do the same without using JSP Servlet or other server side technology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are PaaS/BaaS/MBaaS providers, which you can use to store the answers in the cloud. Some of them offer server-side JavaScript hosting option. I've tried only one (which I am developing).
In case the submitted data isn't sensitive, you can save the answers in a free [JayStorm Open app](http://jaystack.com/blog/jaystorm-open%E2%80%93starting-point) and you can [open the records directly from Excel without writing any code](http://jaystack.com/blog/step-by-step-how-to-and-why-access-your-jaystorm-data-with-excel).
Seems like an hour of development it's OK to build your report using Excel.

There are many BaaS providers, but as I know you need to develop at least in Node to return the results in CSV/XLS from the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote an answer and then deleted it.  I misunderstood your question.

It sounds like what you want to do is collect the data on the web server that the users submit and then format it into an Excel file.

There is a trick that I've used repeatedly for this.

Arrange the data into an HTML table, and save a web page with the table into a file with the .xls extension.  Click on the file and Windows will open the file in Excel.  Excel will interpret the table as a spreadsheet which you can then save as an Excel Spreadsheet.